# Replace String with empty string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, indexof

I have a string that can have the following substring values (includes quotes too)

```
"+form"
"+ form "
" form+"
"form +"
+ form
+form
form+
form +
form   +
+    form
....
....
.... or just simply 'form' that doesnt surrounded by double quotes
```

The problem is to find the substring (+ form or form +) that matches the following

- '+ form' should not be surrounded by quotes
- number of spaces between the '+' and 'form' are not limited

  If it is found, then it should be replaced by the empty string ""

  ```
  Input:
  ' form+ "form" +  form '
  Output:
  "form"
  ```

  > Input:
  >          ' form'
  >          Output:
  >          'form'

Any help?

I'm just at beginner level, and it seems that I cannot solve this with simple replace and index of method :-(

```
var abc = string.replace(" " + "");
 if(abc.indexOf("+form") > -1 || abc.indexOf("form+") > -1 || abc.indexOf("form") > -1 || abc.indexOf("\"+form\"") > -1 || || abc.indexOf("\"form+\"") > -1 )
 {
    // then what should do?
 }
```

Comment: Can you add the JS code you've already tried, please?

Comment: Where do you get that input from? I.e. what is the actual intention?

Comment: I'm creating a application and in that, user enters the code for example("string" + string) and i need to interpret that separately. i.e string denotes variable and "string" denotes the actual string

Comment: Using Regex might be better option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
var input = ' form   + " form " +  form "  form +  " " +   form "'; 
var tmp = input.replace(new RegExp(/\"?\s*form\s*\"?\s*\+\s*\"?/g), ''); //form +
tmp = tmp.replace(new RegExp(/\"?\s*\+\s*form\s*\"?\s*\"?/g), '');// + form
alert(tmp);
```

Had to create two Regex expression one for case where + is before 'form' and another where it comes after. There can be better ways. Some notes below to help understand.

```
\s* -> zero or more spaces  
\"? -> zero or one double quote  
\+  -> one + symbol  
/../g -> replace all matches
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var abc = string.replace(" ", "");
if (abc.indexOf("+form") > -1 {
    abc.replace("+form", "");
}
else if (abc.indexOf("form+") > -1) {
    abc.replace("form+", "");
}
else if (abc.indexOf("form") > -1) {
    abc.replace("form", "");
}
else if (abc.indexOf("\"+form\"") > -1) {
    abc.replace("\"+form\"", "");
}
else if (abc.indexOf("\"form+\"") > -1)) {
abc.replace("\"form+\"", "");
}
```

OR:

```
var array = new Array();
array.push("+form", "form+", "form", "\"+form\"", "\"form+\"");
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
if (abc.indexOf(array[i]) > -1) {
    abc.replace(array[i], "");
}
```

Although it would be maybe better if you use regex.

Comment: It is not recursive and i need the original string with changes made..  Above code can only modifies the trimmed string

Comment: if you input ' form+ "form" +  form ' in the above code, you will get "form" for output.. Try the edit I made

Answer (score 0):

You should try regular expressions. I know they are hard to create and even harder to read, BUT try some of them on this site: http://www.regexr.com/

Here is how to use them: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp

However if you don't like using regexp, you can try creating your finite state machine like Nejc Lovrencic said.

I tried a small regexp and got out with this:

`/[ \t\n\r+]+[^"]\w+[^"][ \t\n\r+]*/g`

What does it do? Well It will tries to find + or empty characters (please correct me if I missed any whitespace character) no quotes, word with more than one character, no quotes, + or empty characters and it will look up globally, means on each line.

Easier would be to look only for "form":

`/\"\w+\"/g`

This looks for word in quotes.

First case replace those words with empty string using replace() function.

`var result = intputString.replace("/[ \t\n\r+]+[^"]\w+[^"][ \t\n\r+]*/g", "");`

Words within quotes plus empty strings will be stored in result .

If you use second case you can easily use:

`var regExp = /\"\w+\"/g
var result = regExp.exec(intputString)`

Words within quotes will be stored in result.

Egain these are regexp that I made in few minutes, but I am certain you can come up with more specific results.

Edit: coppied wrong regexp in first possible case, now it should be ok.